# Trigger a fetch when new model is added to collection (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am making a POST request externally and updating my server, inside my mobile app(seprate from where I am making POST requests), I am trying to make a GET request when that action happens.

Backbone.js has the `listenTo` event, but it seems that's only good when making the POST request from within the app, i.e from the same place the POST requests are being made.

I can update my app when manually entering `myCollection.fetch()` but I am not sure how to get that to trigger on it's own. It seems like its a method that has to be triggered by a human or a setInterval function.

Here is what I have done inside my `initialize` method for my collection view.

```
//Attempt 1
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.collection.fetch);

initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    //Attempt 2
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.collection.fetch({
        success: function() {
            self.render();
        }
    }));
    this.render();
},
```

Those don't work, I am not even sure if its valid, but the idea is to listen to changes on the collection. I may have to manually trigger the fetch?

**Edit:** This is what I am currently trying, is there a better way than making a GET request every `3000ms`?

```
initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
    setInterval(function(){
        self.collection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                self.render();
            }
        });
    },3000);
    this.render();
},
```

**Edit 2:** I added a click event to fetch the data, it seems manually fetching is the only way, similarly to the facebook/twitter refresh method. It seems you cannot listen to a change on the server.

```
App.Views.PlayersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.test',
    events: {
        'click .fetch': 'fetchMethod'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);                      
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            var playerView = new App.Views.PlayerView({ model: model });
            this.$el.append(playerView.render().el);
        }, this);
        this.$el.append('<button class="fetch">Refresh</button>');
        return this;
    }, 
    fetchMethod: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                self.render();
            }
        });
        alert('new item so add was triggered');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah the more I thought about it, I see that I would need PHP or some kind of server solution. But, it is not critical to do that. It is much better to just let the user manually refresh, that along with setInterval every 10 min. That is perfectly fine for me. I would presume most apps do it this way anyhow.

Comment: you will need the server to send a message to your clients to tell them something happened there. sounds like you may need WebSockets or some third party solution like https://pushover.net/

Comment: Hey thanks for that, pushover looks pretty cool!